# Show custom VF pages in Public Knowledge Base frame

Tags: visualforce, case, knowledge, public-group, web2case

I need to show a custom Web-Form (Web-to-case) inside my Public Knowledge Base.
But how can I show it in the "right-content" area of the screen (saying: Popular articles area on the picture).
[image: PKB Template - Showing PKB_Home]

When pressing Contact Customer Service, I want to have the right-content-are navigate to my custom page - Before including the PKB_Template it navigated to the specific page but without the frame, now when included the frame looks fine but the content doesn't show.

How can I kind of define a page with a specific "body" element or similar - to load in the PKB-Template when i click on a link on the PKB site? (Also need to note that the page has it's own custom controller - But if this ruins anything I could include that in the PKB_Controller class.

Below is my VF page with the custom Web-to-case:
[image: Custom Web2case]

Below is my VF-page:

```
<apex:page controller="SubmitWebCaseController" cache="false" standardStylesheets="false"
showHeader="false" sidebar="false" language="{!$CurrentPage.parameters.l}" applyBodyTag="false" applyHtmlTag="false" title="Contact Customer Service" > 
<apex:composition template="pkb_Template">
<apex:define name="body">
<h1>{!$Label.PKB2_Contactform_H1}</h1>
<apex:form >
<apex:pageBlock >
    <apex:pageBlockSection >
    <apex:inputField value="{!c.Subject}" required="true"/><br></br> 
    <apex:inputField label="{!$Label.PKB2_Contactform_DescriptionLabel}" value="{!c.Description}" required="true"/><br></br><br></br><br></br>
    <apex:inputField label=" {!$Label.PKB2_Contactform_PleaseNoPhoneLabel}" value="{!c.Please_no_phone_contact__c}"/><br></br>
    <apex:inputFile title="{!$Label.PKB2_Contactform_AttachFileLabel}" filename="{!at.name}" contentType="{!at.contentType}" filesize="10000" size="50" value="{!at.body}"/><br></br> 
    <apex:commandButton value="Send" action="{!submitCase}"/> 
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:pageBlock>   
<apex:pageMessages />
</apex:form>
</apex:define>
</apex:composition>
</apex:page>
```